# Como posicionar button e .page-header na mesma row (inline)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-3

estou usando o bootstrap para um painel simples e gostária da ajuda de vocês em relação ao posicionamendo de certos elementos na página.

Gostaria de posicionar o botão de salvar junto com o `.page-header`. Porém esta `class` tem a propriedade `display: block;` e estou usando um botão com `class .btn btn-primary btn-block`. O botão está com `display: block`, por causa da `class .btn-block`.

O que eu tentei? Eu removi a `class .btn-block`, e o botão ficou com `display: inline-block`, o que é aceitável, pois eu só precisaria setar a `class .page-header` para ficar com o `display: inline-block` também e isto resolveria o meu problema, pois o botão e o header ficariam na mesma linha. Eu fiz isto, mas eu gostaria que o botão ficasse alinhado a direita, e que o header acompanhasse ele até lá.

Como ficou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu gostaria que ficasse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta segunda print eu consegui fazer utilizando o `position: absolute;`, em conjunto com `top|right`. Porém, se possível, gostaria de uma ideia que **NÃO** envolva trabalhar com o `position`.

Alguém conhece alguma `class` do bootstrap que poderia me auxiliar nesta implementação? Se não, que truque de CSS você usaria para conseguir o resultado da segunda print?

**addendum:**

Sei que dá pra implementar isto facilmente usado o *grid system*. Porém eu não posso utilizar mais rows do que as que já tem. O espaçamento entre as rows já é grande, e eu preciso encaixar este formulário no menor espaço possível. Adicionar outra row seria inviável. Supondo que eu fosse utilizar, eu teria que retirar todos os espaçamentos (margins/paddings) dos outros elementos, fazendo com que o formulário ficasse muito pior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já tentou a class .pull-right?
Pelo que vejo você está usando o Bootstrap, certo? Tente:

```
<span class="pull-right">
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="url">Salvar</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Por gentileza, quem negativar algo indique o porquê da negativação.

Comment: Genos, concordo.

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado pela resposta William! Segundamente, eu usei esta class, e não ficou bem como eu gostaria, mas ficou um resultado bastante aceitável! Obrigado mesmo, resolveu meu problema.

Comment: wdarking conte sempre com a comunidade. Abração Brother. Se puder pontuar a resposta agradeço.